# How to create a user that can login via SSH, but can't use shell commands?

Tags: command-line, ssh, users

How to create a new user that can login via SSH, but can't use shell commands?
I've tried to set `/bin/false` as the default shell to the user, but then I no longer can login via SSH.

Comment: What's the point in logging in via ssh if it's not possible to run commands?

Comment: The only other thing remaining is using specified port forwards to do something else.

Comment: Make a temporary httpforward.
We need it for some users sporadically access.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can create a new, small, "shell" (I used quotes because is not a real shell) as follow:

1. As root, create a new file in `/bin` directory, let say `fakesh`.
2. Add the following code inside `/bin/fakesh` file:

   ```bsh
   #!/bin/bash
   echo -n "$ "
   while read cmd ; do 
       if [ "$cmd" = "exit" ]; then break; fi
       if [ "$cmd" != "" ]; then echo "The only one available command is: exit"; fi
       echo -n "$ "
   done
   ```
3. Save the file and make it executable for everyone:

   ```
   chmod +x /bin/fakesh
   ```

After these, just set `/bin/fakesh` as the default shell for your user. The user will be available to login his account via ssh, but he will not be able to execute any command except for `exit`.

Comment: That was amazing!!
The better ideas is really the simplest ones !!